# Why doesn't the pthread condition variable work

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, race-condition

I'm coding to simulate a selling-ticket situation:
Two threads are selling some tickets one by one and one thread is to show `sold out` when the number of the tickets is 0.
So I try to use a condition variable. Here is the code:

```
int a = 10;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
pthread_cond_t cond;


void * funca(void *p)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        if (a == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        a--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    return NULL;
}

void * funcb(void *p)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        if (a == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        a--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    return NULL;
}

void * funcc(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while(a != 0)
    {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
            printf("I'm nothing");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    printf("sold out\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

However, when I execute the code above, I get a infinite loop with many `I'm nothing` printed.

Comment: You haven't initialised your mutex and condition variable.  Use `pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` and `pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;` when you declare the variables.  (There's also no point having two identical functions for `funca()` and `funcb()`, you can just have two different threads execute the same function).

Comment: @caf  can you please write an answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialised your mutex and condition variable. When you declare the variables, use:

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

There's also no point having two identical functions for `funca()` and `funcb()`, you can just have two different threads execute the same function.